# Снятие слежения с объекта Observable

Tags: android, java, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте. Реализую на Android проект по данному руководству: [Тутор по OneFingerZoom](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/). Задействуется паттерн проектирования `Observer`. В определенный момент работы приложения (поток отработал своё, выставил флаг) требуется убрать слежение за касаниями пользователя по экрану устройства, точнее за изменениями состояния объекта `Observable` (меняет свои состояния на основе координат касания пользователя по экрану, затем сигнализирует об изменениях).

Каким образом убирается слежение за данным событием? Некий метод у наследника `View.OnTouchListener`, класса, реализующего `Observer` или класса, реализующего `Observable`?

Comment: Обычно в реализации присущая какая-то коллекция, которая содержит список слушателей, надо походу как-то извлекать его оттуда =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Из `SDK` по `Observable`:*

> `deleteObserver(Observer observer)`
>
> Removes the specified observer from the list of observers.

Соответственно, в вашем коде из некоторого объекта, реализующего `Observable`, необходимо убрать подписку для конкретного `Observer`. *Точнее **(не видя кода)** сказать сложно.*

Comment: Да. Это работает. Так и действовал. Просто обнаружил логические косяки в своём коде чуть позднее. Все равно спасибо.